# Use negative float values at the input of a MPSCNNGraph

Tags: swift, keras, avfoundation, metal, metal-performance-shaders

I am converting a pertained Keras graph to Metal Performance Shaders (an MPSCNNGraph with layer objects in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metalperformanceshaders/objects_that_simplify_the_creation_of_neural_networks), and cannot get the graph to input or output negative numbers. This is a problem, as the network was trained to take inputs between -1.0 and 1.0.

I am capturing frames from an iPhone camera and converting the SampleBuffers (format kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) into MTLTextures(format MTLPixelFormat.bgra8Unorm(I wanted to use MTLPixelFormat.rgba16Float, but ran into problems converting the SampleBuffers to MTLTextures when doing so)).

The first layers of the graph look like:

```
    let input = MPSNNImageNode(handle: nil)

    let scale = MPSNNLanczosScaleNode(source: input,
                                      outputSize: MTLSize(width: 256,
                                                          height: 256,
                                                          depth: 1))

    let bgrSwap = MPSCNNConvolutionNode(source: scale.resultImage,
                                        weights: ConvDataSource("BGRLayer"))
```

"bgrSwap" converts from bgr to rgb, and applies f(x) = 2x - 1 to each pixel (to convert the [0,1] output from the LanczosScaleNode to the desired range [-1.0,1.0]).

When I convert the bgrSwap.resultImage to floats (using helpers from @Hollance's https://github.com/hollance/YOLO-CoreML-MPSNNGraph/blob/master/TinyYOLO-NNGraph/TinyYOLO-NNGraph/MPSImage%2BFloats.swift (thank you hollance! i hope i'm not misapplying this extension)), I see only values in [0.0,1.0]. I have a suspicion that there is some conversion going on behind the scenes that prevents me from seeing the results before they are (rescaled?), but I am not sure.

Comment: What is the pixelFormat of the texture from bgrSwap.resultImage?

Comment: float16. This is the graph's verbose output: MPSNNScale[1] {1080 x 1920 x 3 unorm8}[2](offset:0) -> {256 x 256 x 3 float16}[1]  offset: 0  "(null)"
 padding policy: AlignCentered, AddRemainderToTopLeft, SizeSame, 
MPSCNNConvolution[0] {256 x 256 x 3 float16}[1](offset:0) -> {256 x 256 x 3 float16}[0]  offset: 0  "BGRLayer"
 padding policy: AlignCentered, AddRemainderToTopLeft, SizeSame,

Comment: whoops, thats .rgba16Float

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is? The input is unorm8, which is RGB values that get normalized to the range [0, 1]. Then your BGRLayer works on float16s. That's also normal. So there's nothing strange about the pixel formats. Are you saying that the BGRLayer is supposed to do the `2x - 1` normalization but somehow doesn't? I'm not sure why you'd be using a convolution for that, but I'd double check that your weights make sense and all the other settings in your ConvDataSource class.

Comment: The problem is that (from what i can tell) the output at each layer of the graph is never negative. As a test I set the bias on BGRLayer to -1000.0 and looked at the outputs, they never passed below zero. I will double check the weights, it must be a conversion problem. I'm using a convolution with kernel size 1 to transpose channels, so figured i'd toss scaling in there as well

Comment: Just so you know, you can get RGB to BGR for free when you use a "texture view" on the original input texture. And you can do the scaling with a linear neuron. That might be easier than using a convolution layer.

Comment: I fixed the problem i was having by explicitly setting the graph format to .float16, I'll  check out the texture view, thanks!

Comment: It is fairly common to run a linear neuron filter after the scale to convert [0,1] to [-1,1]. Perhaps you forgot a step.